# whitelist custom html tags "Server Side Excludes (SSE) from Cloudflare" on angular 8

Tags: angular, express, cloudflare, angular-universal

Cloudflare, have Server Side Excludes (SSE), however, the tag `<!--sse--><!--/sse-->` is removed when is deployed as angular universal - expressjs.

How do I whitelist those tags on angular? I'll appreciate an example.

```
<!--sse-->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<!--/sse-->
```

[image]

For more information about those tags:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170036-What-does-Server-Side-Excludes-SSE-do-

Comment: Does that help? https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20180316-CreatingHtmlCommentsInAngular.html

Comment: actually no, breaks when the app when render as universal. so this case, the solution was to add the comment Cloudflare tag to index.html

Comment: So the issue is solved?

Comment: yes we found a solution

Answer (score 0):

the solution for this case was to add directly to the index.html

```
        <body>
          <!--sse-->
          <app id="app"></app>
          <!--/sse-->
        </body>
```